# Ruby - How can i convert a mixed number to float?

Tags: ruby

I need to convert a mixed number to float type, for eg: 1 1/2 to 1.5.

Is there any built in method in ruby to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split into pieces, convert the pieces to [Rationals](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html), sum the Rationals, and convert the result to a Float:

```
s = '1 1/2'
f = s.split.map { |r| Rational(r) }.inject(:+).to_f
# 1.5
```

If you know that the string will always have two parts then you could handle the pieces separately:

```
s = '1 1/2'
a = s.split
f = a.first.to_i + Rational(a.last).to_f
# 1.5
```

If you're not sure how many parts there will be (i.e. `'1'`, `'3/2'`, `'11 23/42'`, ... are all possible) then the first one should work in all cases.

[Kernel#Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Rational) will raise an ArgumentError if it can't parse the string so you might want to wrap the whole thing in a `begin`/`except` block to deal with errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '1 1/2'
w, e, d = s.strip.match(/\A(\d+)?\s*(?:(\d+)\/(\d+))?\z/).to_a.drop(1).map(&:to_f)
w + (e / d) # => 1.5
```