# Dealing with Mixed Numbers — In Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with a large number of fields that I am storing in my database as decimals.

However, I'd like the user to be able to input fractions, and specifically mixed numbers (e.g. 38 1/2)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515470/ruby-how-can-i-convert-a-mixed-number-to-float) provides a good solution for converting mixed numbers to fractions, and I've modified it and put it in a function in my model:

```
def to_dec
  self.chest = self.chest.split.map { |r| Rational(r) }.inject(:+).to_f
end
```

And I've experimented calling it with `validate :to_dec` and `before_save :to_dec`. However, neither of these work.

I know why, but not how to fix it.

By using `puts self.chest` I'm able to tell that the value is being converted to a number before I have a chance to tweak how that's done. Entering '10 1/2' into my form and saving, `puts self.chest` gives me 10.0 even if the function is just:

```
def to_dec
  puts self.chest
end
```

In addition, `puts '38 1/2'.split.map { |r| Rational(r) }.inject(:+).to_d` gives me 38.5, so I know the problem is not in the converting.

I've changed the view input type from number to string, but I seem to still end up with a number in my model.

I'm stuck.

Also, some of the other fields also need to support mixed numbers—I'd like to abstract this out somehow so I don't need to write a different function for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that ActiveRecord looks at your database schema when it defines your model attributes. This is how all the attributes appear on your model class without you ever defining them manually with `attr_accessor :chest` (or `def chest` and `def chest=`) like you would have to on a plain old Ruby object.

When it does so, ActiveRecord also looks at the column types, and applies type casts when assigning attributes. Hence, because your `chest` column is a decimal, it converts any string you give it to a float. In doing so it will grab the first bit of the string that can be converted, and discard the rest, which is why you get `38.0`.

You can get around this in a couple of ways - you could either just store the numbers as strings in the database, which might save a few conversions (but wouldn't be so useful if you need to use the numeric representation in queries), or you could use a [virtual attribute](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes).

Basically, you need to define a getter and a setter like so:

```
def rational_chest
  # I assume this would create a rational from a float
  # and respond to `to_s` in a sane manner...
  Rational(chest) if chest
end

def rational_chest=(value)
  self.chest = parse_rational(value)
end

private

def parse_rational(value)
  return nil if value.blank?
  value.split.map{|r| Rational(r)}.inject(:+).to_f
end
```

Then use `rational_chest` in your form instead of just `chest`

Since you need to do so on a number of fields, you could resort to a bit of nifty metaprogramming:

```
def self.rational_attribute(attribute)
  define_method("rational_#{attribute}") do
    Rational(send(attribute))
  end

  define_method("rational_#{attribute}=") do |value|
    send "#{attribute}=", value.split.map{|r| Rational(r)}.inject(:+).to_f
  end
end

def self.rational_attributes(*attributes)
  attributes.each {|attribute| rational_attribute attribute}
end

rational_attributes :chest, :waist, :etc
```

If you use this in several models, chuck it in a module (without the `self.`s and `extend` it!

Comment: I edited your answer with `if chest` because it was throwing an error if left blank. Really helpful and well explained! One downside is this allows improper fractions (77/2, etc)  but that's easy to solve by removing `Rational()`. Which gives a decimal. Eventually I may convert it back to a mixed number using this [gem](https://github.com/clord/fraction). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmmm... I was able to fix the problem with leaving a blank value for the first example, but I'm struggling with the second. I'd like to allow a blank input. Any ideas? I'm getting this error `undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Ah yep good call, I hadn't thought about that case. I'd probably split the parsing into a separate method, as shown in my latest edit. Overall it sounds like your needs are a little more complicated than the basic `Rational` class you have, perhaps it would be worth considering developing a custom `Measurement` class instead.

Comment: Also, `chest_was` should give you the value before rails converts it to the type defined for that attribute in the database.

Comment: I'm getting some errors about nil again when I create a new record, but it goes away if I remove `Rational()` from `send(attribute)`. Though, not a problem for my use case...

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble doing any validation while using this. Any tips?

Comment: @bookcasey you should probably ask a separate question about that!

Comment: @AndyH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848252/dry-up-this-model-with-virtual-attributes :-)