# DRY up this model with virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form I have a virtual attributes that allows me to accept mixed numbers (e.g. 38 1/2) and convert them to decimals. I also have some validations (I'm not sure I'm handling this right) that throws an error if something explodes.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mixed_chest

  attr_writer :mixed_chest

  before_save :save_mixed_chest

  validate :check_mixed_chest

  def mixed_chest
    @mixed_chest || chest
  end

  def save_mixed_chest
    if @mixed_chest.present?
      self.chest = mixed_to_decimal(@mixed_chest)
    else
       self.chest = ""
    end
  end

  def check_mixed_chest
    if @mixed_chest.present? && mixed_to_decimal(@mixed_chest).nil?
      errors.add :mixed_chest, "Invalid format. Try 38.5 or 38 1/2"
    end
  rescue ArgumentError
    errors.add :mixed_chest, "Invalid format. Try 38.5 or 38 1/2"
  end

  private

  def mixed_to_decimal(value)
    value.split.map{|r| Rational(r)}.inject(:+).to_d
  end

end
```

However, I'd like to add another column, wingspan, which would have the virtual attribute `:mixed_wingspan`, but I'm not sure how to abstract this to reuse it—I will be using the same conversion/validation for several dozen inputs.

Ideally I'd like to use something like `accept_mixed :chest, :wingspan ...` and it would take care of the custom getters, setters, validations, etc.

**EDIT:**

I'm attempting to recreate the functionality with metaprogramming, but I'm struggling in a few places:

```
def self.mixed_number(*attributes)
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    define_method("mixed_#{attribute}") do
      "@mixed_#{attribute}" || attribute
    end
  end
end

mixed_number :chest
```

This sets chest to "@mixed_chest"! I'm trying to get the instance variable `@mixed_chest` like I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators)

Something like

```
class MixedNumberValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.present? && MixedNumber.new(value).to_d.nil?
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "Invalid format. Try 38.5 or 38 1/2")
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do

```
validates :chest, mixed_number: true
```

Note that I'd extract the `mixed_to_decimal` stuff into a separate class

```
class MixedNumber
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    @value
  end

  def to_d
    return nil if @value.blank?
    @value.split.map{|r| Rational(r)}.inject(:+).to_d
  rescue ArgumentError
    nil
  end
end
```

and that this definition lets you drop the `if` statement in the `save_chest` method.

Now you just need to do some metaprogramming to get everything going, as I suggested [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811107/725792) to your other question. You'll basically want something like

```
def self.mixed_number(*attributes)
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    define_method("mixed_#{attribute}") do
      instance_variable_get("@mixed_#{attribute}") || send(attribute)
    end

    attr_writer "mixed_#{attribute}"

    define_method("save_mixed_#{attribute}") do
      # exercise for the reader ;)
    end

    before_save "save_#{attribute}"
    validates "mixed_#{attribute}", mixed_number: true
  end
end

mixed_number :chest, :waist, :etc
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, Andy. I'm working my way through the answer, trying to understand every part. I know the `if ... else self.chest = ""` part is sort of dumb, but when I remove it deleting the value doesn't change it. It just reverts to what it was.

Comment: In addition, I'm struggling with setting instance variables, which I've added to my updated question.

Comment: Ok I added a bit more detail to help you with the metaprogramming. What happens if you replace the `self.chest = ""` in the `else` to `self.chest = nil` (because that is what should happen when the conversion fails once you remove the `if` altogether).

Comment: `self.chest = nil` works in the `else `. However, I remove all of that logic, it attempts to `to_d` `nil` and I get this error: `undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass`. Also, one *final* question, how do I get `self.chest` within the generated methods. I've tried `self.attribute` and a bunch of other things that are wrong. :-)

Comment: Yeah, you're looking for `send(attribute)` (or `send("#{attribute}=", value)` for the setter)... `some_object.send` takes a method name (as a symbol or a string) and calls that method on `some_object`. You don't usually need to do `self.send` though because the `self` is implicit.

Comment: I edited the `MixedNumber#to_d` method to deal with the case when it was trying to do `nil.to_d`.